# Reaction mechanism validity

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrocarbons

Hey I was solving some questions i found this solution to a question
[image]

I'm confused, can alpha-hydroxy acids undergo dehydration??

Answer (score 2):

Two different things are  happening here. Firstly the hydroxy group is the first site of protonation, then water leaves resulting in formation of the double bond, a standard dehydration. Second the nitrile is protonating and undergoing hydrolysis (mechanism [here](https://www.chemistrysteps.com/the-mechanism-of-nitrile-hydrolysis-to-carboxylic-acid/)) to the carboxylic acid *via*
the amide. This usually takes forcing condtions, but with hot 95% sulfuric acid that is what you've got.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i thought that it was alpha hydroxy elimination

Comment: @AwadheshPrajapati  if you are happy with the answer please accept it